# For which tax(es) do the country of residence matter for Alaska Airlines' Fly & Buy Miles™?

Tags: usa, air-travel, residency, taxes, alaska-airlines

I read on https://www.alaskaair.com/Booking/Seats/SelectSeats:

> Your country of residence determines what taxes, if any, are applicable to any additional purchases such as Fly & Buy Miles™.

Do they only refer to the 7.5% excise tax that [applies](https://viewfromthewing.com/when-you-buy-miles-from-a-us-airline-you-can-get-the-7-5-tax-refunded/) to airline tickets for flight within the US and sold by US airlines, or are there other taxes that may also apply?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some jurisdictions charge sales or value added taxes on transactions such as miles purchase.